# sap.ushell.ui.shell.ShellHeadItem does not show the text

Tags: sapui5

In the [`SAPUI5 documentation`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.ushell.renderers.fiori2.Renderer%23methods/addHeaderEndItem) they have the following example for adding a header item to the launchpad top header toolbar.

```
var oRenderer = sap.ushell.Container.getRenderer("fiori2");

    // Create an icon button that opens a dialog
    oRenderer.addHeaderEndItem({
        id: "myTestButton",
        icon: "sap-icon://action-settings",
        tooltip: resources.i18n.getText("testButton.tooltip"),
        text: resources.i18n.getText("testButton.text"),
        ariaLabel: resources.i18n.getText("testButton.ariaLabel"),
        ariaHaspopup: "dialog"
        press: [myController.handleTestButtonPress, myController]
    }, true);

    // Create a temporary link
    oRenderer.addHeaderEndItem({
        id: "myTestLink",
        ariaLabel: resources.i18n.getText("testLink.label"),
        target: "#MyTestApplication-show"
        icon: "sap-icon://overflow"
    }, true, true);
```

I have tested this snippet, unfortunately it only shows icon and it does not show any text, however the tooltip works!

Anybody have any idea that how can I force `sap.ushell.ui.shell.ShellHeadItem` to show text instead of icon!? Or at least show both icon and text!

When I only set the text and do not set the icon property it will show this result:

[image]

Comment: https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/button/ >> A button can contain an icon OR a text

Comment: Hey @Marc. I have updated the question. When I only set the text it shows a missing picture sign! I've already tested this also.

Comment: I don't find the reference but you also shouldn't mix text and icon buttons. Ofc in an app you can do whatever you want, but in the launchpad header it is probably enforced. If you check the Diagnostics tool you'll see that the controls knows its text, but it will not be rendered (probably due to usability/constistency)

Comment: of course it has text, but for me it seems it is more a bug or maybe some settings in the renderer is missing. Anyway, the code provided by SAPUI5 documentation itself and not by me.